# How POSIX compliant is "/path/file/.."?

Tags: bash, sh, posix, cd, ash

I wanted to change current directory into shell script into directory, containing specific regular file. I found that following trick works in `mksh` and `busybox sh`:

```
path=/path/to/regular/file
cd $path/..
```

but not in GNU Bash:

```
bash: cd: /path/to/regular/file/..: Not a directory
```

Is this trick not posix-compatible, or Bash is too pedantic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latest edition of the standard doesn't allow that. [POSIX.1-2017 `cd` spec.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) says that if the pathname component preceding dot-dot is not a directory, `cd` shall consider that an error.

From [`cd` § *DESCRIPTION* - step 8.b](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_03:%7E:text=For%20each%20dot-dot%20component,an%20appropriate%20error%20message%20and%20no%20further%20steps%20shall%20be%20taken.):

```
b. For each dot-dot component, if there is a preceding component and
   it is neither root nor dot-dot, then:

    i. If the preceding component does not refer (in the context of
       pathname resolution with symbolic links followed) to a
       directory, then the cd utility shall display an appropriate
       error message and no further steps shall be taken.
```

When `cd` is invoked with `-P` option, this step is omitted; but then [`chdir()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) fails if one of the pathname components names an existing file that is neither a directory nor a symbolic link to a directory.

Besides, permitting that *trick* also allows inconsistent behavior in `cd`. For example, when run in a directory containing a **regular file** named `bar`, and a **directory** named `foo` containing another **directory** named `bar`, the following two commands do different things in a shell where `cd` ignores non-directory components preceding a dot-dot, despite that `CDPATH` contains the empty string (i.e. *the current working directory*) in both cases.

```
CDPATH= cd bar/..
```

```
CDPATH=:foo cd bar/..
```

Below transcripts visualize the difference between non-conforming and conforming implementations clearly.

```
$ tree -F
.
├── bar
└── foo/
    └── bar/

2 directories, 1 file
```

```
$ ash
$ CDPATH= cd bar/..
$ pwd
/home/oguz
$ CDPATH=:foo cd bar/..
/home/oguz/foo
```

```
$ bash
$ CDPATH= cd bar/..
bash: cd: bar/..: Not a directory
$ CDPATH=:foo cd bar/..
/home/oguz/foo
```

[bosh](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html), [gwsh](https://github.com/hvdijk/gwsh), [ksh93u+m](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh), and [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp/index.html.en) are other actively maintained shells that implement the same behavior as bash.